# Can't get the Place details (Gmaps Places API) more than 20 data

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm quite a newbie in Python espescially to use Gmaps API to get place details.

I want to search for places with this parameters:

```
places_result  = gmaps.places_nearby(location=' -6.880270,107.60794', radius = 300, type = 'cafe')
```

But actually i want to get many data as i can in the specific lat/lng and radius. So, I try to get new parameters that google api has provided. That's page_token. This is the detail of documentation:

> **pagetoken** — Returns up to 20 results from a previously run search. Setting a pagetoken parameter will execute a search with the same parameters used previously — all parameters other than pagetoken will be ignored.
> https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

So i tried to get more data (Next page data) with this function:

```
places_result  = gmaps.places_nearby(location=' -6.880270,107.60794', radius = 300, type = 'cafe')
```

`time.sleep(5)`

`place_result  = gmaps.places_nearby(page_token = places_result['next_page_token'])`

And this is my whole output function:

`for place in places_result['results']:`

`my_place_id = place['place_id']`

`my_fields = ['name','formatted_address','business_status','rating','user_ratings_total','formatted_phone_number']`

`places_details  = gmaps.place(place_id= my_place_id , fields= my_fields)`

`pprint.pprint(places_details['result'])`

But unfortunately when i start to running i only get 20 (Max) data of place details. I don't know whether my function of page token parameter it's true or not, because the output can't get more than 20 data.

I'm very appreciate for anyone who can give me an advice to solve the problem. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging):

> By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20 establishment results per query; however, each search can return as many as 60 results, split across three pages.

So basically, what you are currently experiencing is an intended behavior. There is no way for you to get more than 20 results in a single nearby search query.

If a `next_page_token` was returned upon sending your first nearby search query, then, this means that a second page with results is available.

To access this second page of results, then just like what you did, you just have to send another nearby search request, but use the `pagetoken` parameter this time, and set its value with the `next_page_token` you got from the first response.

And if the `next_page_token` also exists on the response of your second nearby search query, then this means that the third (***and the last***) page of the result is also available. You could access the third page of results using the same way you accessed the second page.

Going back to your query, I tried the parameters you've specified but I could only get around 9 results. Is it intended that your `radius` parameter is only set at 300 meters?

Comment: Hi! Any chance you can share the code you used to do this?